# Divide N items into M groups with as near equal size as possible

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms, divisibility

Im trying to split (say) `N` pink, fluffy balls into `M` groups as evenly as possible.

Eg: `9 Balls` and `4 groups`, i'd have a result set of the form: `{3,2,2,2}`, where each value is indicating the size of each subset.

Can anyone help me understand how to write an equation or algorithm that would solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Well, you say "divide": so look at division: what information does it tell you? Can you use that to help solve the problem?

Comment: Aside: you probably didn't mean "result set", because "set" is usually used to refer to a collection that doesn't count repetition: the sets {3,2,2,2} and {3,2} are the same.

Comment: Ah yes, its flooding back to me now. cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are given $N$ and $M,$ you put $\lfloor \frac NM \rfloor+1$ in $N \pmod M$ of the groups and $\lfloor \frac NM \rfloor$ in the rest.

Comment: Thanks, was thinking along the lines of this. Think I was going for something like set all to n/m, then a for loop, 1 to (n Mod m) adding one.